# Первый консольный калькулятор

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Изучаю Java 3 месяц всего, вот написал свой первый консольный калькулятор. Собственно хотел услышать мнение опытных разработчиков, указать на ошибки в применении принципов ООП, и вообще на сколько в коде применялось оно(нормально, либо ужасно). И может быть указания которые помогут применять эти принципы более правильно. Я уже много раз перечитывал, разные главы из книг, на тему Классов методов интерфейсов и все что с ними связанно, но никак не могу найти всему этому логически правильное применение, когда например писал этот самый калькулятор.

https://gist.github.com/redento/25b6fd2784e9192e035f6f463a6634e3

```
package Beginner;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import static Beginner.ReplaceFizzBuzz.j;

public class Calculator {
   static ArrayList mem = new ArrayList();
    static   BufferedReader inc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static String ravno = "=";
    static double resl = 0;

    public static Double parsing() throws IOException {
        try {
            System.out.println("Введите число:");
            String j = new String(inc.readLine());
            String lower = j.toLowerCase(); //Переводим строку в нижний регистр
            if (j.equals("=")) {                 //Если сразу ввели = сообщаем что это не в тему сейчас
                System.out.println("Сразу равно? Введите число еще раз!");
                return parsing();
            } else if (lower.equals("число")) { //если пользователь ввел "Число" буквами, сообщаем что он клоун
                System.out.println("А вы шутник сэр! Введите число еще раз");
                return parsing();
            } else {

                resl = Double.parseDouble(j);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) { //если пользователь ввел недопустимый символ, строку, обрабатываем это исключение
            System.out.println("Сэр, я не понимаю что вы пишите!? Введите число еще раз!");
            return parsing();
        }
        return resl;
    } //Метод первой инициализации
    static public void SysMess() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Здравствуйте!!! Я мистер Кальконс, приступим к расчетам...");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("-> Для получения результата введите: '='");

        System.out.println("-> Чтобы узнать процент от числа введите: '%' Пример 60 % 100 = 60");

        System.out.println("-> Чтобы я запомнил результат, в поле (Введите знак) введите ++. Я могу помнить только 10 чисел.");
        System.out.println("-> Чтобы посмотреть что хранится в моей памяти, в поле (Введите знак) введите +++");
        System.out.println("-> Чтобы стереть мою память, в поле (Введите знак) введите -- (два минуса).");
    } //Системные сообщения перед запуском программы
    static Double plus () throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Введите число:");
        try {
            String f = new String(inc.readLine());
            String lower = f.toLowerCase();
            if (lower.equals("=")) {
                System.out.println("Результат: "+resl);
                System.out.println("Сэр вы хотите считать еще? Y да N нет");
                String yn = new String(inc.readLine());
                String low = yn.toLowerCase();
                if (low.equals("y")|low.equals("yes")|low.equals("да")){
                    return parsing();
                }else if (yn.equals("n")) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                    System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю сэр. До скорой встречи!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                }
            resl = resl + Double.parseDouble(f);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            System.out.println("Вы ввели не число, будьте внимательнее!");
            return plus();
        }
        return resl;
    } //Обработка операции + плюс
    static Double minus () throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Введите число:");
        try {
            String f = inc.readLine();
            if (f.equals("=")) {
                System.out.println("Результат: "+resl);
                System.out.println("Сэр вы хотите считать еще? Y да N нет");
                String yn = inc.readLine();
                String low = yn.toLowerCase();
                if (low.equals("y")|low.equals("yes")|low.equals("да")){
                    return parsing();
                }else if (yn.equals("n")) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю сэр. До скорой встречи!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            resl = resl - Double.parseDouble(f);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели не число, будьте внимательнее!");
            return minus();
        }
        return resl;
    } //Обработка операции = минус
    static Double umnojit () throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Введите число:");
        try {
            if (resl == 0) {
                System.out.println("Сэр вы собираетесь умножить 0 на число!");
            }
            String f = inc.readLine();
            if (f.equals("=")) {
                System.out.println("Результат: "+resl);
                System.out.println("Сэр вы хотите считать еще? Y да N нет");
                String yn = inc.readLine();
                String low = yn.toLowerCase();
                if (low.equals("y")|low.equals("yes")|low.equals("да")){
                    return parsing();
                }else if (yn.equals("n")) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю сэр. До скорой встречи!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            double um = Double.parseDouble(f);
            resl = resl * um;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели не число, будьте внимательнее!");
            return umnojit();
        }
        return resl;
    }//Обработка операции * умножить
    static Double delenie() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Введите число:");
        try {

            String f = inc.readLine();
            if (f.equals("=")) {
                System.out.println(resl);
                System.out.println("Сэр вы хотите считать еще? Y да N нет");
                String yn = inc.readLine();
                String low = yn.toLowerCase();
                if (low.equals("y")|low.equals("yes")|low.equals("да")){
                    return parsing();
                }else if (yn.equals("n")) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю сэр. До скорой встречи!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            } else if (f.equals("0")) {
                System.out.println("Вы пытаетесь делить на 0!");
                return delenie();
            }
            resl = resl / Double.parseDouble(f);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели не число, будьте внимательнее!");
            return delenie();
        }
        return resl;
    }//Обработка операции / делить
    static Double precent() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Введите число:");
        try {
            String f = inc.readLine();
            if (f.equals("=")) {
                System.out.println("Результат: "+resl);
                System.out.println("Сэр вы хотите считать еще? Y да N нет");
                String yn = inc.readLine();
                String low = yn.toLowerCase();
                if (low.equals("y")|low.equals("yes")|low.equals("да")){
                    return parsing();
                }else if (yn.equals("n")) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю сэр. До скорой встречи!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            resl = (resl * Double.parseDouble(f)) / 100;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели не число, будьте внимательнее!");
            return precent();
        }
        return resl;
    }//Обработка операции % процент от числа
    static Double pasing2 () throws IOException {
        while (ravno.equals("=")) {
            System.out.println("Введите знак:");
             String zn = inc.readLine();
            //пилим ниже..
            if (zn.equals("++")){
                if(mem.size()>=10){
                    System.out.println("Я не могу запомнить больше сэр");
                }else{
                mem.add(resl);
                System.out.println("Я запомнил результат сэр! "+resl);
                System.out.println("Считаем заново");
                parsing();
                pasing2();
                }
            }else if(zn.equals("--")){
                if(mem.size()==0){
                    System.out.println("Я и так ничего не помню сэр!? Что мы тут вобще делаем!?");
                    System.out.println("Считаем вроде:");
                    parsing();
                    pasing2();
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Я забыл ваш результат сэр!");
                    mem.clear();
                    System.out.println("Считаем заново:");
                    parsing();
                    pasing2();
                }
                }else if (zn.equals("+++")){
                try{
                    if(mem.size()==0){
                        System.out.println("Я ничего не помню сэр!");
                    }else {
                    System.out.println("Сэр вот числа которые вы прросили меня запомнить: "+mem);}}
                catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                    System.out.println("Я ничего не помню сэр!");
                }
                System.out.println("Считаем заново:");
                parsing();
                pasing2();
                }
            //пилим выше!
            if (zn.equals("=")) {
                System.out.println("Результат: "+resl);
                System.out.println("Сэр вы хотите считать еще? Y да N нет");
                String ynn = inc.readLine(); //Вводим да или нет
                String low = ynn.toLowerCase();//форматируем регистр строки в Нижний!
                if(low.equals("y")|low.equals("yes")|low.equals("да")){ //если да очищаем результат и начинаем считать все заново
                    resl = 0; //очищаем результат
                   parsing(); // вызываем 1ую инициализаию
                    pasing2();// вызываем 2ую иницаиализацию рекурсивно
                }else if(ynn.equals("n")|ynn.equals("no")|ynn.equals("нет")){//если ввел пользователь нет -n- очищаем переменную, которая меня бесит, зачем она бля?
                ravno = "";//вот как мне ее заменить на чтонибудь нормальное хз, пока..
                }else{ // если пользователь ввел чтото отличное от y,n обижаемся и закрываемся.
                    System.out.println("Для меня это значит нет! Досвидания сэр!");
                    ravno =""; //тут мы обиделись и закрылись
                }
                break;
            } else {
                switch (zn) {

                    case "+":
                        plus();
                        break;

                    case "-":
                        minus();
                        break;

                    case "*":
                        umnojit();
                        break;

                    case "/":
                        delenie();
                        break;

                    case "%":
                        precent();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return resl;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        SysMess(); // вывод системных сообщений в начале работы программы
        parsing(); // метод начального ввода
        pasing2(); //метод инициализации

    }
}
```

Comment: ну пакеты и методы принято называть с маленькой буквы.

Comment: Первое, что бросилось в глаза – это транслит в названиях методов. Не делайте так. И не забывайте про `UpperCamelCase` для именования классов/интерфейсов и `lowerCamelCase` для именования методов и переменных.

Comment: И как такового ООП я там не увидел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Переменные должны быть приватными, если вы не используете их из вне на прямую.
2. Почитайте книжечку ***Code Conversions for the Java*** - поможет в оформлении кода.
3. Если это калькулятор, то было бы логичней сделать несколько дочерних классов от *ICalc*, и реализовать функцию `calc(params)`, какую функцию она выполняет - одну из главнейших - расчет результатов операции.
4. Куча лишних условий